# Merge these two array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge two arrays where first array will be keys and second array will be values in result array.

```
$array1 =array('k1','k2');
$array2 =array('v1','v2');
```

output should be:

```
array(

    'k1' => 'v1',
    'k2' => 'v2',
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `array_combine` function. This function uses one array for keys, and one array for values.

You can use it as:

```
array_combine ( $keys, $values );
```

In your case it would be:

```
$array1 =array('k1','k2');
$array2 =array('v1','v2'); 

$combined_array = array_combine ( $array1, $array2 );
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the built in [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) function

```
$keys   = array('k1','k2');
$values = array('v1','v2'); 
$result = array_combine ($keys, $values);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a1=array("a","b","c","d");
$a2=array("Cat","Dog","Horse","Cow");
print_r(array_combine($a1,$a2));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

array_combine() function in php is most simplest way to do this:

```
$array1 =array('k1','k2');
$array2 =array('v1','v2'); 

$result_array =  array_combine ($array1, $array2);
```